# Registering the Touch Event on Android for half the screen

Tags: android, input, touch

I am attempting to get my program to recognize whether the user touches the left half of the screen or the right half of the screen without using buttons, so I looked into using the onTouchEvent methods.

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't seem to work, it only reads as a left half touch anywhere that I touch it.

```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int y = (int)event.getY();

        if ((y < (width / 2)) {
        someint = 1;
        } else if ((y > (width / 2)) {
        someint = 2;
        }
     }
   }
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using .getX()......

Comment: try using event.getRawX(); without casting it to int.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys! It was a combination, I needed the X instead of Y and event.getRawX() got it working, just had to change int y to float y